# No module named 'faker.proxy'

Tags: python, import, python-import

```
    from faker.proxy import Faker
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'faker.proxy'
```

or this error:

```
 from faker import Faker
ImportError: cannot import name 'Faker' from 'faker' (--path--/main/faker/__init__.py)
```

...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use pip to install it ?
If not, I recommand you to do it by writing in your cmd :

```
pip install nameOfYourModule
```

Comment: i installed bruh :\